# How to test component that should throw an error?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

My component throw error (**and should be**)

```
function ProblemChild() {
    throw new Error("Error thrown from problem child");
    return <div>Error</div>; // eslint-disable-line
}
```

My question is .. how can I test this??

```
const wrapper = mount(<ProblemChild />);
```

Something like this..

```
expect(wrapper).toThrow()
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap mounting within callback. Like so:

```
expect(() => mount(<ProblemChild />)).toThrow()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
it('should throw an error when there is an error', () => {
  try {
    wrapper.setState({error: true});
    expect(true).toBe(false); //Fail test if no error is thrown
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error).toBe(error); //Pass test if an error is thrown
  }
});
```

In the example above i have the error in the state. It can be possible that your function is called onClick or onChange. In that case you have to use a [simulate event](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html) before the assertion.